# Jupyter How to grab entire rows that matches certain value

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a table named `park` like below.

```
Lon Lat City
 1   1   A
 1   2   A
 2   3   B
 3   4   C
```

I want to grab the rows of City A only (the data frame with matching value of "A") so that it looks like below

```
Lon Lat City
 1   1   A
 1   2   A
```

**How can I do this?**
Edit:
I realized that the example in the first link works but on my data it does not work. Why would this happen?

(My actual data contains Japanese characters so I am used a simplified version above.)

What I tried and did **NOT** work:

### isin

I followed [this](https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_select_rows_when_column_has_certain_values/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas) ran below but they both return empty

```
value_list = ["北海道"] 
park[park.Prefecture.isin(value_list)] # returns empty 
park.loc[park["Prefecture"].isin(["北海道"])] # returns empty
```

Screenshots

Data
[image]

Empty result
[image]

Comment: `df[df.City.eq('A')]`

Comment: @anky_91 it doesn't work

Comment: doesnt work for the example you shared or your actual data?

Comment: @anky_91 actual data.. do you think there is a chance that somehow my titles are not mapped with the csv data? because I did `park.columns = ["Longitude", "Latitude", "Name", "Kind", "Prefecture", "City", "Open Date", "Area", "Planned"]` after I import CSV

Comment: print `df.City.unique()` and see if the value you are searching for is there. There are chances that there are spaces in the name

Comment: `[' 北海道' ' 青森県' ' 岩手県' ... ' 宮崎県' ' 鹿児島県']`
Oh my god there are... let me remove them and re-do it

Comment: @anky_91 Got it now. You are a life-saver. Please add it to the answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `City` column has spaces, please remove them :

Either trim the column using `=TRIM()` before reading into Pandas,

Else `df.City=df.City.str.strip()` will strip the trailing whitespaces.

Post that use:

```
final=df[df.City.eq('A')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using something like this.

```
df[df['city']=='A']
```

this will return a dataframe only consisting of City A so you can use that dataframe to get your data.